# Dockerizer Maven multimodule project (angular + java) with strong coupling dependency

Tags: java, angular, spring, docker, maven

I have a multi-module maven project like:

```
myProject
  - /module1 (angular)
      - package.json
      - pom.xml
  - /module2 (java)
      - /target
      - pom.xml
- pom.xml
```

I tried:

1. One Dockerfile multistage like :[multi-module Maven project on Dockers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51679363/multi-module-maven-project-on-dockers) => it's doesn't work because of permission denied with yarn install.
2. Two Dockerfiles, one for front (with a yarn install directly), and the second for the rest (back and parent maven project) => the image of front is empty as if it doesn't accept a yarn install inside a maven module.
3. Four DockerFiles, one for every pom.xml a Dockerfile => problem with strong coupling dependencies with front and back

Do you have any other ideas please or solutions?